# JQuery AJAX URL Local or Absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a portion of my web application that uses AJAX. I am using the JQuery AJAX call to add and remove items from the users shopping cart, and it works fine. The URL that I pass as a parameter in the AJAX call is the url-mapping defined in the web.xml file, minus the leading forward slash.

I tried to replicate this with another place in the application where I would like to use AJAX, but this time, the Servlet GET is not even being called at all. I have alerts in the javascript function, so I know the function is being called. Is there a way that I can see (within the ajax function call) what the fully qualified URL is that the GET request is being made to? Also, what is the 'rule' with respect to the AJAX URL? Is there a way that I can get to the context root? My Servlet is mapped to www.mydomain.com/contextRoot/un

I would rather not have to hardcode the context root into the function call, that way if it ever changes, I don't have to update all my javascript functions.

Comment: Ajax requests that do not start with a `/` (or the full domain path) are relative to the current HTML file path.

Comment: okay, so if I start with a / do I have to then specify the context root?

Comment: I see examples quoting `var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;` however I'm not sure if the browser detects the `host` part correctly. Give it a try. The alternative is to inject the server root into the page... what is your server technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The "rule"

Ajax requests (or any http request from the page) that does not start with a / (or the full domain path) is *relative to the current HTML file path*.

### How to view GET requests

Use the debugging tools in Chrome/Firefox or something like [Fiddler2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

### How to get server root

If it is a simple `www.host.com`:

```
var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
```

(Not sure if this works for context based domains).

You do not mention what server technology you are using, but if you are using MVC/Razor you can inject the server root into a Javascript variable with something like this in your master page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    window.domainRoot = "@(Url.Content("~/"))";
<script>
```

this injects a javaScript line like:

```
  window.domainRoot = "http://www.mydomain/mycontext/";
```

you can then reference `window.domainRoot` from any JavaScript code.

If you are using PHP there will be an equivalent way to inject the server root.

Answer (score 1):

A simple browser debugger (F12) and you can read the network traffic send.

From here it is possible to see all the details (sent and/or received)

Comment: Ok, I will give this a try

Comment: While this is a useful *tip* (should have been a comment), this is not an answer to the actual problem (how to provide server-relative URLs for Ajax?).

Comment: But well done on getting multiple up-votes for answering 1 of the 3 questions asked :)

Answer (score 0):

I think The url  plus parameter is  contextRoot/un?para=***.

Comment: In a word... Eh? They need to know how to use server-root relative URLs without hard-wiring the `contextroot`.